# Adding item to dynamic list

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, dom, dynamic

I'm trying to add text items from the user to a dynamic list. I tried but not getting it. How to go about it...thanks.

```
<div id="displayList"></div>
```

Add Text

```
<script>
var displayList = document.getElementById('displayList')
var inputTxt = document.getElementById('inpText')
var listArray = ['Orange', 'White', 'Green'];
    var li;
    var ul = document.createElement('ul')
    var len = listArray.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            li = document.createElement('li')
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(listArray[i]))                       
            ul.appendChild(li)
        }

    displayList.appendChild(ul)


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#displayList').append(ul);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually, I know that the code that I sent works fine. What I'm after is to and an item to the array list from the use after the list is loaded. If the user wants to add another color say PURPLE from a input box and then click a button 'Add Item' it shoudl add to the displayed LIST. How do i do that? I tried using listArray.push('Purple'), but it doesn't add.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work just fine as you can see.

```js
var displayList = document.getElementById('displayList')
var inputTxt = document.getElementById('inpText')
var listArray = ['Orange', 'White', 'Green'];
    var li;
    var ul = document.createElement('ul')
    var len = listArray.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            li = document.createElement('li')
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(listArray[i]))                       
            ul.appendChild(li)
        }

    displayList.appendChild(ul)
```

```html
<div id="displayList"></div>
```

So the only problem that might exist is if the script is run before the DOM is ready and thus the `document.getElementById('displayList')` does not return anything because the `displayList` does not yet exist.

Try running your script at the end of the file. Or run it after the DOM ready event (*in the `DOMContentLoaded` event*)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var displayList = document.getElementById('displayList')
    var inputTxt = document.getElementById('inpText')
    var listArray = ['Orange', 'White', 'Green'];
        var li;
        var ul = document.createElement('ul')
        var len = listArray.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                li = document.createElement('li')
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(listArray[i]))                       
                ul.appendChild(li)
            }

        displayList.appendChild(ul)
}, false);
```